# SQL Server - sysjobhistory - Has no rows for the job that executed

Tags: sql-server

I have a job that runs 3 times in a day. I queried the msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory to find the job history. However I found no rows

I know that SQL Server, maintains 100 rows per job and the sql server agent job properties have the limit set to 100 records per job and 1000 records overall. And this is the setting I have too

Any ideas on why there are no records for the job that ran

Thanks
Rathi

Comment: Maybe the job never ran?

Comment: Open up the actual Job and click View Job History on the bottom left--do you see anything there either? What is the last executed time?

Comment: The "1000 records overall" is important. If you have other jobs executing much more frequently, that limit can be hit easily, crowding out less frequently executing jobs. How many rows are there in the job history in total?

Comment: The job runs at 5 am, 1 pm and 8pm. Strangely, after the completion of the 5 am job I do not find any history for the job that has run. But after the 2 pm run, I find history for the job in msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory. The total number of rows is 1003, which is again strange When I right click on the View job history I do not find any details. However,I know the job has run as I have the latest data in my tables

Comment: If, between 5 AM and whenever you look at the table, there have been 1000 executions of other jobs in total, the history will have disappeared. Jobs can run with intervals as small as 10 seconds, so this is easy to achieve. On all our production servers, we execute `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties @jobhistory_max_rows=100000,  @jobhistory_max_rows_per_job=1000;` to set the total limit to 100.000 and the per-job limit to 1000. This consumes at most 200 MB in `msdb`, which I've never found to be a problem (unlike missing history).

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I am sorry I am not able to understand. I did not get as to why the rows are deleted. Because the same number of jobs run all day.